# Salvar vários registros no banco

Tags: php, mysqli, loop

Estou usando o seguinte código sem sucesso.

```html
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','banco');
    try {

        $body = file_get_contents("php://input");

        $dados = json_decode($body);

        foreach($dados as $dataone){
          $nome = $dataone['nome'];
          $img = $dataone['img'];
          $qtd = $dataone['qtd'];        
        
            $sql = "INSERT into tabela (nome,img,qtd) values ('{$nome}','{$img}','{$qtd}')";
            
            $qr=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);        
      }
```

Comment: Qual é o problema ? Está retornando erro ? ..

Comment: Não está salvando

Comment: Agora que notei, falta uma aspa simples aqui: `({$nome}',`

Comment: Era esse o problema  ?

Comment: Não era... É um json que vem do APP e salvo no banco, se executo fora do for ele salva sempre a última linha, nas dentro do for não salva nada

Comment: Amigo, posta o código do arquivo JSON que está sendo enviado, sem ele fica difícil responder sua pergunta. O problema aqui é que você ta tratando o arquivo JSON decodificado como um array, mas na verdade ele é um objeto com vários atributos. É preciso saber como esses atributos estão organizados para poder gravar eles no banco de dados corretamente.

Comment: @CloudAC, está enviando assim para p php:

{ nome: "Pedro", img: "images/pedro.png", qtd: "5"}, { nome: "João", img: "images/joao.png", qtd: "8"}, { nome: "Jose", img: "images/jose.png", qtd: "7"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguinte, acredito que primeiramente, o próprio arquivo JSON que está sendo enviado para o servidor php contém erros, verifique novamente o código JSON que está sendo enviado e compare com o que eu vou postar. 
Arquivo JSON que deveria ser enviado ao servidor PHP:

```
{
    "pessoas": 
    [
        {   "nome": "Pedro", 
            "img": "images/pedro.png", 
            "qtd": "5"
        }, 
        {   "nome": "João",
            "img": "images/joao.png",
            "qtd": "8"
        }, 
        {   "nome": "Jose",
            "img": "images/jose.png",
            "qtd": "7"
        }
    ]
}
```

Script PHP para inserir dados do arquivo JSON no banco:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","banco");

        try {

            $body = file_get_contents("php://input");

            $dados = json_decode($body);

            for($i = 0; $i < count($dados->pessoas), $i++){

                $nome = $dados->pessoas[$i]->nome;
                $img = $dados->pessoas[$i]->img;
                $qtd = $dados->pessoas[$i]->qtd;

                $sql = "INSERT into tabela (nome,img,qtd) values ('$nome','$img','$qtd')";

                $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                if ($query){
                    echo "Dados inseridos no banco com Sucesso";
                } else {
                    echo "Houve um erro enquanto tentava inserir dados no banco : " . mysqli_connect_error($conn);
                }   
            }

          }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Veja se com o script abaixo funciona, se não funcionar, observe o erro gerado e poste aqui nos comentários:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","banco"); // Se não funciona, tente com a linha abaixo
    //$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","banco");
        try {

            $body = file_get_contents("php://input");

            $dados = json_decode($body);

            foreach($dados as $dataone){

                $nome = $dataone['nome'];
                $img = $dataone['img'];
                $qtd = $dataone['qtd'];        

                $sql = "INSERT into tabela (nome,img,qtd) values ('$nome','$img','$qtd')";

                $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                if ($qr){
                    echo "Sucesso";
                } else {
                    echo "[ERRO]: " . mysqli_connect_error($conn);
                }               
          }
?>
```

Comment: O código que esá sendo enviado para o php:

{ nome: "Pedro", img: "images/pedro.png", qtd: "5"},
{ nome: "João", img: "images/joao.png", qtd: "8"},
{ nome: "Jose", img: "images/jose.png", qtd: "7"}

Answer (score 0):

**Obs: minha tabela com latin1_general_ci**

Essa não é minha praia, porém fiz um teste e só obtive sucesso fazendo essas alterações:

Na pagina usei:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

O código enviado para o php com a seguinte sintaxe:

```
$body = '[{ "nome": "Pedro", "img": "images/pedro.png", "qtd": "5"}, { "nome": "João", "img": "images/joao.png", "qtd": "8"}, { "nome": "Jose", "img": "images/jose.png", "qtd": "7"}]';
```

As letras acentuadas causam erros (João), usei `utf8_encode`.

**utf8_encode** - decodifica uma string no padrão ISO-8859-1 para o padrão utf-8.

```
$body = utf8_encode ($body);
```

e finalmente usei:

```
$dados = json_decode($body,true);
```

> `json_decode` analisa a string codificada JSON e converte-a em uma variável do PHP, quando TRUE, o retorno será convertido em array associativo.